# How manifest.json can ignore a specific folder under it's scope?

Tags: web-applications, manifest.json

I've set up the "start URL" and "scope" of manifest.json to the root of the site.

```
"start_url": "./index.html?addToHome=true",
"scope": "./",
```

But I want it to ignore a specific folder positioned under this root.
Is there a way to do it?

```
_ website-directory
|_ /other-app/   (how to ignore this?)
|_ index.js
|_ index.html
|_ manifest.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think their is a way for excluding the particular folder,but you can provide relative path something like `"scope": "/myapp/"`